# Filter a DataSet by the current date

Tags: c#, dataset, filtering

I have a column 'date' in my DataSet. I would like to filter this column by the current date.
I want to display all the orders just for today (current date).

I tried this but it's not working:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("C:\\sites.xml");

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;

//filter
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "date = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "'";
```

XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<sites xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <site technical="1">
        <name>brian</name>
        <url>www.microsoft.com</url>
        <date>01/02/2012</date>
    </site>
    <site technical="2">
        <name>Mike</name>
        <url>www.news.com</url>
        <date>01/02/2012</date>
    </site>
    <site technical="3">
        <name>leslie</name>
        <url>www.cnet.com</url>
        <date>02/01/2012</date>
    </site>
    <site technical="4">
        <name>rebeca</name>
        <url>www.gamespot.com</url>
        <date>01/01/2012</date>
    </site>
    <site technical="5">
        <name>jenifer</name>
        <url>www.google.com</url>
        <date>02/01/2012</date>
    </site>
</sites>
```

Comment: "It's not working" does not provide as much information as people think it does. If it's an error, provide the message. If it's an unexpected result, tell us what that was and what you expected.

Comment: I didn't have an error message and my columns are empty into the datagridview when I tried to filter.Perhaps it's the XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use number sign **`#`** instead of apostrophe **`'`**.

Try this:

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "date = #" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "#";
```

source: http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

**UPDATE:**

base on the date from your XML record, format date with "**MM/dd/yyyy**"

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "date = #" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "#";
```

Comment: Single quote can be used in pace of #.

Comment: same thing with #... datagridview empty

Comment: the code works if I put "date >" or "date <" but not if I put the date =. I think the problem is the =... why?

Comment: I found.... the problem was DateTime.Now.ToString()... I replaced by  DateTime.Today . Problem solved thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "date = #" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "#";
```